# How to make title in column cell of NSTableView?

Tags: cocoa

How to display title in column cell of NSTableView?

Answer (score 1):

Double click column header and type in anything you need

Comment: But i want to display dynamic.is it possible?

Comment: Yes, in code fetch a column in question then adjust it's headerCell's title property: `[[column headerCell] setTitle:@"foobar"]`